# Бот не отвечает на сообщение в беседе

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Есть команда `баланс`, после написания которой бот выводит сообщение с балансом пользователя. Если это сообщение будет написано в лс с ботом, то бот выведет баланс пользователя, если в беседе, то ответа не будет. Как я понимаю бот не может взять айди пользователя через `message.chat.id` в беседе, но как тогда правильно брать айди пользователя в беседе?

```py
elif message.text.startswith('баланс') or message.text.startswith('бал') or message.text.startswith('Бал') or message.text.startswith('Баланс'):
        my_balance(message)

def my_balance(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT balance, bank FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    for user in users:
        bot.reply_to(message, text=f' Ваш баланс: {user[0]:,}\n Банковский счет: {user[1]:,}')
```

Comment: Вместо `message.chat.id` попробуйте `message.from_user.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените на

```
    user_id = message.from_user.id
```

В личных чатах с ботом `message.from_user.id` и `message.chat.id` всегда равны друг другу, поэтому их часто путают, и не придают этому особого значения, хотя отвечают они за совершенно разные вещи.

`message.from_user.id` -  это id пользователя, который написал сообщение (не важно куда, в личный диалог с ботом, или в группе)

`message.chat.id` - это id чата, в который пришло это сообщение.

Comment: Нуу, зачем дословно копировать комментарий) Его и так отлично видно. Я понимаю, если бы что-то сложное, что надо разжевать.

Comment: Вас не смущает что ответы данны практически одновременно?) Быть может когда  я начинал отвечать вашего коммента еще не было?)

Comment: Да, я прокомментировал еще до правки с внесением изменений. Теперь, конечно, все нормально.